# How to stop dynamically loaded playing video when bootstrap modal closes

Tags: javascript

I'm loading multiple videos into one bootstrap modal, which works. However, when a video plays and the modal is closed, the video continues to play in the background. I've seen many posts about how to stop video, but they don't work here (I assume it has something to do with the way the iframe is constructed).

```
 <div class="container">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="517580922" data-toggle="modal">Video A</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="546013845" data-toggle="modal">Video B</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="516281261" data-toggle="modal" >Video C</button>     
               
<!-----   The MODAL --------------->
         <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="background-color:;">
            <div class="modal-dialog" style="background-color:white;">
                  <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:white; margin-bottom:-23px;">
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="font-size:63px;">&times;</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        <iframe id="video" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/516281261" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
         </div>    
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(e) {

    // opens modal, changes video src to parameter passed from button press

    $(document).on("click", ".modalButton", function() {
        var ClickedButton = $(this).data("name");
        $(".modal-body").html('<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe id="video" class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ClickedButton+'" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>');
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
       
    
    // to turn video off when modal closed (does not work) 
    /*
    $(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal({
        show: false
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        $(this).find('video')[0].pause();
    });
    */
    
    
    // to turn off video when modal closes (does not work)
    $('#video').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#video').attr('src', $('#video').attr('src'));
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: It's is not possible to access the video element as you are using iframe. You can remove that iframe when the modal get closed.

Comment: Got it!  I just added this and it works:       $(function(){
        $('.close').click(function(){      
            $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));
        });
    });